# recyclerview can't display list more then 7

Tags: java, android, mobile, fragment

recyclerview can't display list more then 7

Comment: Please reformat your post.  Additionally, it might be useful to post your view as well.

Answer (score 2):

Android's recycler views get the number of elements to display from the `getItemCount` method.

Since `getItemCount` returns 7, because there are 7 elements in the images array, only 7 elements are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

the images array  count is only 7.

Answer (score 0):

As Arun has already answered your question , still you want more details to clear for you .

You said how to display recyclerview more than 7 ,
for this simply add more items in images array :
Replace images array with the following .

```
int images [] = {R.drawable.greasy_fast_food,R.drawable.greasy_fast_food,R.drawable.greasy_fast_food,
            R.drawable.greasy_fast_food,R.drawable.greasy_fast_food,R.drawable.greasy_fast_food,R.drawable.greasy_fast_food , R.drawable.greasy_fast_food,R.drawable.greasy_fast_food,R.drawable.greasy_fast_food};
```